# List of items in FastAPI response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

In my Fast API app I have this pydantic model

```
class UserInArticleView(BaseModel):
    """What fields will be in nested sent_to_user list."""

    telegram_id: int

    class Config:
        """Enable ORM mode."""

        orm_mode = True

class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str = Field(..., min_length=50, max_length=1024)
    image_url: HttpUrl = Field(..., title="Image URL")
    language_code: str = Field("ru", max_length=3, min_length=2)
    sent_to_user: List[UserInArticleView] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

The response is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Some text",
    "image_url": "http://test.tt/",
    "language_code": "ru",
    "sent_to_user": [
      {
        "telegram_id": 444444444
      },
      {
        "telegram_id": 111111111
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to have a response with "sent_to_user" as a list of values, like below?
The reason is I need to check IN condition.

```
"sent_to_user": [
  444444444,
  111111111
]
```

The final solution is:

```
@app.get("/articles/{article_id}", tags=["article"])
def read_article(article_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    """Read single article by id."""
    db_article = crud.get_article(db, article_id=article_id)
    if db_article is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Article not found")
    list_sent_to_user = [i.telegram_id for i in db_article.sent_to_user]
    print("list", list_sent_to_user)
    return list_sent_to_user
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you can create a new pydantic model that extends your `ArticleBase` model and reassign the type of `sent_to_user` to a `List` of `int` and use this template for your response

```py
class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    text: str = Field(..., min_length=50, max_length=1024)
    image_url: HttpUrl = Field(..., title="Image URL")
    language_code: str = Field("ru", max_length=3, min_length=2)
    sent_to_user: List[UserInArticleView] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class ArticleResponse(ArticleBase):
    sent_to_user: List[int] = []
```

Then, you have to format your answer to fit the requested format:

```py
list_int = [elt['telegram_id'] for elt in result_articles['sent_to_user']]
```

example integration:

```py
@router.get('/articles/{article_id}',
    summary="get article"
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    response_model=ArticleResponse)
def update_date(article_id:int):
   articles = get_article(article_id)
   articles.sent_to_user = [elt.telegram_id for elt in articles.sent_to_user]

   return articles
```

The code has not been really tested, it is only intended to give an idea of integration of the code provided

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Editing of the answer. You need to format your model's answer before returning it

Comment: I can't understand where do I need to add this code?

Comment: Editing of the answer again for add an integration example.

Comment: Well, it worked this way `list_sent_to_user = [i.telegram_id for i in db_article.sent_to_user]`

Comment: But I still can not get right response `AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'dict'`

Comment: It was just an example to adapt. But I modified it to make it work

Comment: This way we need to remove response_model as well, otherwise it gives an error

Comment: Normally, that work. Edit your first message and add your code, where you fit that